# Magento2: Dynamically save system xml custom field issue

Tags: magento2

```
$url = "http://api.abc.com/";
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'accept: application/json'
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_getinfo($ch);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $response; 
        $this->configWriter->save('grazz_auth/graz_settings/expiry_date', $response);
```

This is saving on the second time submit on save config button. Not working on first save.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: please go through the error log an share the details if there is any?

Comment: What is the method you are using for this action? Can you update your code to the question?

Answer (score 0):

replace your code from :

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response; 
$this->configWriter->save('grazz_auth/graz_settings/expiry_date', $response);
```

to

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);     
$response; 
$this->configWriter->save('grazz_auth/graz_settings/expiry_date', $response);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: This is not working

Comment: have you sure that, you get value first time from that one?

Comment: I am not getting value first time

Comment: Have you try to debug the code? Does where it wrong the first time.

Comment: Actually when I click second time submit config then i get the response value not on first time